# Basic ASP.NET MVC4 project does not validate html5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, validation

Am I missing something here?

If I try to validate the basic HTML5 masterpage template of a new basic MVC 4 project, it doesn't validate.
What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


</body>
</html>
```

both this validator: http://html5.validator.nu/ and the w3 one give the same errors:

> Error: Stray end tag head.
>   From line 9, column 1; to line 9, column 7
>   dernizr")↩↩
>   Error: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.
>   From line 10, column 1; to line 10, column 6
>   )↩↩↩ ↩

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are validating against the raw Razor source, which is intended to be interpreted by the web server, not a web browser. You should validate against the generated HTML.